# ModuleNotFoundError when run python script but in cmd prompt type 'import colorama' is works

Tags: python-3.x

Window10 and Python3.7.4

The lib I am trying to use is 'colorama'.

When i run the python script file (x.py) it cannot find the module in the line which is "import colorama", but when i open a cmd and enter python env then type 'import colorama', it works. Does any one know what's the reason?
'''

```
>>>D:\Scratch\commands>mypythonscript.py
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>  File "D:\Scratch\commands\mypythonscript.py", line 12, in <module>
>>>    from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
>>>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
```

'''
I don't know why this issue arise but maybe I installed VS2019. Before this, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find which python your are working with using SYS module with its VERSION method in this way:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

And then verify if you are using the same python version as you are using on cmd.

Another problem could be the path of your module, try to locate it with the "magical method" of your module installed, for example in this case:

```
import colorama
print(colorama.__file__)
```

And then verify if colorama is in this path: ".../Python37/lib/site-packages/colorama"

if not, download COLORAMA from here:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

unzip it with 7ZIP
and all unzip files copy to : ".../Python37/lib/site-packages"
don't worry for the module version, colorama is for all python versions.

NOTE: this only works for windows version.

Comment: yes it works for me. the script python is using 3.7.2 but i really don't know why it exists in my disk. I removed the folder and now it can locate to my v3.7.4. Thanks very much~